# How to exclude Domain from autowiring when declaring service with Symfony 4.1.3?

Tags: symfony, service, domain-driven-design, autowired

I'm working on a light DDD app with Symfony 4. In my `services.yaml` file, I configured the autowiring as such:

```
services:
# default configuration for services in *this* file
_defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                        # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                        # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

# makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
# this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DataFixtures,Migrations,Tests,Domain/IceCream/IceCream.php,Domain/Cake/Cake.php,Domain/Candy/Candy.php}'
```

I excluded all the entities since they're not services. As you might have noticed, I listed all corresponding files because when I type :

```
exclude: '../src/{DataFixtures,Migrations,Tests,Domain}'
```

a runtime exception is raised: `Cannot autowire service : "App\Application\Query\Cake\CakesQueryHandler": argument "$cakeRepository" of method "__construct()" references interface "App\Domain\Cake\CakeRepositoryInterface" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this interface to the existing "App\Infrastructure\Doctrine\Repository\Cake\CakeRepository" service.`
The first service, which is a queryhandler, is not autowired.

How can I exclude the whole Domain without having to type all files within it ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

As you said to me directly, the runtime error you have is :

`(1/1) RuntimeException
Cannot autowire service "App\Application\Query\Cake\CakesQueryHandler": argument "$cakeRepository" of method "__construct()" references interface "App\Domain\Cake\CakeRepositoryInterface" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this interface to the existing "App\Infrastructure\Doctrine\Repository\Cake\CakeRepository" service.`

In your query handler, you want to inject a service with is typed as `App\Domain\Cake\CakeRepositoryInterface`.

As a matter of fact, you have declared a service for your category repository with  the name : `App\Infrastructure\Doctrine\Repository\Cake\CakeRepository`.

To fix this, you need to add an alias from your interface to your repository in your `services.yaml` file :

`App\Domain\Cake\CakeRepositoryInterface: '@App\Infrastructure\Doctrine\Repository\Cake\CakeRepository'`

Comment: @kinedie we really appreciate your thanks but best way to thank someone on Stack Overflow is to accept the answer and upvote it :)